# JQuery Tablesorter, SortList not working after changing selectorSort

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQueryTableSorter on a table, with an  tag in each header, that acts like a button for dropdown menu

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th><div class="clickable">column 0 </div><div class="non-clickable"><img></div> </th><th><div class="clickable">column 1</div><div class="non-clickable"><img></div></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td> cell00 </td> <td> cell01 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> cell10 </td> <td> cell11 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> cell20 </td> <td> cell21 </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I dont want clicking on the img to sort the column, so i edited the tablesorter plugin:
I changed (row 96) `selectorSort     : '> thead th, > thead td'` to `selectorSort     : '.clickable'` and its working (mostly) as intended. The problem is that i want to be able to sort (Asc or Desc) by clicking another button. I was using `$("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0]} );` to sort by the first column, but after editing the plugin, its no longer working.
Here is the console.log that i get when clicking on column 0:
"***Sorting on 0,0 and dir 0 time (2ms)***"

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0]} )` to `$("#mytable").data('tablesorter').sortList = [[0,0]];
 $("#mytable").trigger('update');` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use the [`sorton` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sorton)

```
// Choose a new sort order
var sort = [[0,0],[2,0]],
    callback = function(table){
        console.log('new sort applied');
    };
// Note that the sort value below is inside of another array (inside another set of square brackets)
$("table").trigger("sorton", [sort, callback]);
```